# Installation progress stopped with CleverStack

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have this problem to create a new project with CleverStack. The installation progress stopped on 64%.

Preparing for installation...

```
└── Creating project installation path...
```

Installing Backend...

```
├── Installation path is /Users/XXXX/Documents/project/my-first-app/backend...

├── Downloading and extracting node-seed...

├── Creating local configuration file config/local.json...

├── Installing NPM modules...

└── Installing module dependencies...

✔ Backend installation has completed successfully!
```

Installing Frontend...

```
├── Installation path is /Users/XXXX/Documents/project/my-first-app/frontend...

├── Downloading and extracting angular-seed...

├── Installing NPM modules...

├── Installing bundled modules...

├── Installing bower components...


Status @ 65.083m | Installation Progress: [▒▒▒▒▒▒----] 64 % ┊ Installing: Frontend 
┊ Step: Installing bower components... ┊ Step Time: 61.333m ┊
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: was there any error message further below? To me it looks like it was doing fine and was taking just longer than expected?